# createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not executing futher

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know why but following portion of the is not executing further. only the ***whenComplete*** is executing and giving results.

```
UserCredential result = await fireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).whenComplete(() => debugPrint("CREATE USER COMPLETE"));

globals.user = result.user!;
debugPrint(globals.user);
debugPrint("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ result is $result");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the async call with an error handler, may be an error is being thrown.

```
try {
  UserCredential result = await fireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  debugPrint("CREATE USER COMPLETE");
  globals.user = result.user!;
  debugPrint(globals.user.toString());
  debugPrint("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ result is $result");
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint("Error creating user: $e");
}
```

Also you are using the null assertion (!) for the result.user but if result.user is null it will throw a runtime error and the subsequent lines won't execute.